# auth_key is required : Quickblox error

Tags: java, rest, quickblox

I am using Quickblox REST APIs. When i am trying to run from POSTMAN , it is giving me proper output. but , when i am using it through my java code. It is showing me below error :

`auth_key is required`

Here is my java code :

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.quickblox.com/session.json");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

String current_date = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
Date newdt = dateFormat.parse(current_date);
long unixTime = newdt.getTime() / 1000;
String nonce = randomString(5);
String message ="application_id=XXXXX&auth_key=XXXXX&nonce=xxxxtimestamp=xxxx";
JSONObject arrayElement = new JSONObject();
arrayElement.put("application_id", "xxxxxx");
arrayElement.put("auth_key", "xxxxxxx");
arrayElement.put("nonce", nonce);
arrayElement.put("timestamp", unixTime);
arrayElement.put("signature", hmacDigest(message, secret, "HmacSHA1"));
conn.setRequestProperty("data", arrayElement.toJSONString());
conn.connect();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
HashMap hmdata = new HashMap();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
      hmdata.put("data", inputLine);
   }
in.close();
```

Can anybody help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send as json then add the following header:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

because the server does not understand in what format you send the request's payload

Comment: yes. working now. my issue was with sending input to rest client. so , i have used outputstream, code is working fine now. Changed "Accept" to "content-Type" for sending data in json object